# mongoose findByIdAndUpdate - check field and modify it

Tags: mongoose, findandmodify

I have the following code:

```
 Something.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.query.id,
    { $inc: { available: -1 } },
    { new: true, useFindAndModify: false },
    (err, book) => {
  );
});
```

I want to update the available field only if it is greater than 0. I could look for the item check if its field is bigger than 0 and then if it, look for it again and update it. Is there a way to do this using only a function?

Comment: You can use [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html), match conditions would be `{ _id: req.query.id, available: { $gt: 0 } }`

Comment: You're right this will do exactly what I wanted, I thought there may be a way with ```findByIdAndUpdate```. Thanks you